# Cannot display unicode chars on Apache but works fine in shell using Python 3

Tags: apache, python-3.x

I have what seems to be a very simple problem yet after much searching I just cannot figure it out. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")
print()
print("<html><body>Testing unicode: テスト</body></html>")
```

When I run it from the shell, it works fine:

```
# ./test.py
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<html><body>Testing unicode: テスト</body></html>
```

But for some reason, nothing shows up when loading the page in a browser. My Apache error_log shows this:

```
[Fri Jun 03 00:11:30.079830 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 27507] AH01215:   File "/var/www/html/test.py", line 4, in <module>
[Fri Jun 03 00:11:30.079849 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 27507] AH01215:     print("<html><body>Testing unicode: \\u30c6\\u30b9\\u30c8</body></html>")
[Fri Jun 03 00:11:30.079872 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 27507] AH01215: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 29-31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I even have `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in my httpd.conf. Anyone knows what could possibly be wrong?

**EDIT:** What particularly pisses me off is that I tried the same code in Perl and PHP and both display fine in the browser. I thought Python 3 was always Unicode by default? I just don't know what to do here, I have fairly long amount of Python code that I can't just rewrite, or go in and manually encode/decode every string.

This is on a pretty basic CentOS 7 running on AWS.

Comment: Are you sure that default python version on your system is Python 3? When you run script from shell, it will use python3 as written in shebang: `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`. But your apache can use another python version, check `ldd mod_wsgi.so`, for example, if you are using mod_wsgi.

Comment: I don't have that module. I'm not actually sure which CGI module it runs, my 01-cgi.conf has:   <IfModule mpm_worker_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
   LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
   LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
</IfModule>

Comment: Besides wouldn't Apache's CGI module just load the file using the same interpreter in the shebang? If I write a bash script and write `#!/usr/bin/bash` it will run it with bash..

Comment: Try `apache2ctl -M` to see which cgi module is currently enabled.

Comment: `apachectl -M|grep cgi   
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)  
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)  
 cgi_module (shared)  
`

Comment: Solved it by adding `SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8` in Apache config. Still baffled why Python CGI defaults to ASCII when every other language I tried works just fine with unicode. Anyways...